# Getting issue when using JGroups in Fuse ESB 7.1.0

Tags: jboss, infinispan, jgroups, fuseesb

I am using Infinispan which uses JGroups

When I run my code on a Windows platform it works fine.

But when runnning on Linux I get the following exception:

failed sending discovery request
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:676)[:1.7.0_17]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MPING.sendMcastDiscoveryRequest(MPING.java:300)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.sendDiscoveryRequest(Discovery.java:259)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.sendDiscoveryRequest(Discovery.java:259)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.findMembers(Discovery.java:216)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.findAllViews(Discovery.java:203)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.down(Discovery.java:527)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2$FindSubgroupsTask.findAllViews(MERGE2.java:326)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2$FindSubgroupsTask._findAndNotify(MERGE2.java:261)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2$FindSubgroupsTask.findAndNotify(MERGE2.java:249)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2$FindSubkgroupsTask$1.run(MERGE2.java:226)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.util.TimeScheduler2$RecurringTask.run(TimeScheduler2.java:603)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.util.TimeScheduler2$MyTask.run(TimeScheduler2.java:535)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.util.TimeScheduler2$Entry.execute(TimeScheduler2.java:440)[143:xxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jgroups.util.TimeScheduler2$1.run(TimeScheduler2.java:297)[143:xxxxx:2.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_17]

How can I achieve this

Comment: Possibly the interface being used cannot handle multicast requests. Anyway consider moving this question to ServerFault, as it is probably not suitable for SO (as it's not programming related).

Comment: Possibly related: [Web app won't join Infinispan cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10188156/2390083)